# Return the difference of multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, codeigniter

how can I compare these two arrays?
I want the result be elements that are not available in one array. For example:

**Array #1**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => 3
    )
)
```

**Array #2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => 2
        )
)
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => 3
        )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Have you looked at the php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#refsect1-function.in-array-examples

Answer (score 0):

In **set theory** this is call *symmetrical difference*.

First you need to remove any possible duplicates, then get the individual differences for both arrays and the merge those two individual differences.

```
$a = array('John', 'Bob', 'Mary', 'Serena');
$b = array('Jim', 'Mary', 'John', 'Bob');

// Remove any duplicates
$a = array_unique($a);
$b = array_unique($b);

// Get the individual differences, using array_diff()
$a_minus_b = array_diff($a, $b);
$b_minus_a = array_diff($b, $a);

// Simply merge them together to get the symmetric difference
$symmetric_difference = array_merge($a_minus_b, $b_minus_a); // produces ['Serena', 'Jim']
```

You may need to make the necessary changes for a 2D array if you need to.

I hope this help.

Comment: Your example is for single dimension arrays, though. The one shown here is multi-dimensional. Besides, I don't see the need of so much hassle for 1-d arrays. You could have simply used array_diff() function, had it been single dimensional, haha. :)

Comment: @ObjectManipulator I'm just making a start point, as he/she doesn't input any code I assume he/she doesn't know how to begin. That's why I said at the end that changes may be done for multi dimensional arrays. I assume he/she doesn't want someone to write the entire code for him/her.